# php symfony/dom-crawler, парсинг картинок

Tags: php, парсер, img, phpquery

Добрый день.
Есть необходимость в парсинге страницы яндекс.маркет (ничего криминального, правда - просто тестовое задание).
Использую symfony/dom-crawler, html получаю через curl:

```
function getHTML(string $url): string
{
    $optionsArray = array(
                    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
                    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => false,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
                    );

$ch = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt_array($ch, $optionsArray);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if($result === false) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Cant load HTML');
} else {
    return $result;
}}
```

Описание товара и прочего парсится как-то так:

```
$products = $crawler->filter(".n-snippet-card2")->each(function(Crawler $node, $i){
    $currentProduct['title'] = trim($node->filter(".n-snippet-card2__title a")->text());
    $currentProduct['price'] = trim($node->filter(".price")->text());
    $currentProduct['about'] = trim($node->filter(".n-snippet-card2__content")->text());
    return $currentProduct;
});
```

Появился вопрос о парсинге картинок: есть ли какой-нибудь более адекватный способ вытаскивать картинки, кроме как забирать url картинки из тэга "img", скачивать картинку по этому url и записывать в базу?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как же по-другому?

Браузеры ведь именно так и скачивают.

Скачивать по "src", не забыв абсолютизировать урл. Класть картинку куда нужно)